# Dataweave: Opening and Closing Tags Namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, dataweave

I have a namespace on my DataWeave map. I would like the namespace attribute on the opening tag but not as an attribute on the closing tag.

```
{ 'trace xsi:type="trace"':
```

Closing XML Tag to should be

`</trace>`

But currently getting

`</trace xsi:type="trace">`

Comment: Can you please give a fully reproducible paired down example showing input and expected output so we can help?  Looks like you have some invalid json there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please provide a more complete example of your data-weave. I'm going to assume you're doing something like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{ 
    'trace xsi:type="trace"': {
        'somethingElse': null
    }
}
```

Which produces:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<trace xsi:type="trace">
  <somethingElse/>
</trace xsi:type="trace">
```

It is doing this because you've told data-weave the entire string (`'trace xsi:type="trace"'`) consisting of your key, namespace, and attribute key/value are all one string, representing the key. It doesn't know that that is an attribute key/value with a namespace because you've hardcoded it.

Here is how you SHOULD be doing this (see docs: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-insert-attribute and https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-include-xml-namespaces)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
---
{
    trace @(xsi#'type': 'trace'): {
        'somethingElse': null
    }
}
```

Which produces:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<trace xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="trace">
  <somethingElse/>
</trace>
```

Don't manually put in your namespaces and attributes, let data-weave handle it by using the appropriate data structure.